# Slow Adobe Flash Pro CS6

Tags: windows-7, windows, adobe-flash

I'm trying to make a .swf flash for a game suggestion. I know how Flash works and all, I used it a ton on my other computer, it's just I got a new computer and this one is weird. When I first turn it on it works really, really fast. Than after I use for for 2-5 min I greatly see it got slower. When I turn it on it's at 10/10. After 2 min it's at 8/10 than after 10 min it's 2/10.

I'm running **Adobe Flash Pro CS6**

- Windows 7 x64
- Intel Core i3 540 @ 3.07 3.06 GHz
- 12 GB RAM

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What are you doing that makes the computer slower? Can you give **objective** readings like in Task Manager? Can you give more information as to your machine?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the Flash settings?  This question is very hard to read.

Comment: When I read this question, I'm not sure if you're saying that the **computer** you're using gets slower, or if the **application** you're using is getting slower. Can you make that a little more clear?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing it is probably what you are working on, your history, and probably you undo list. Try changing them to a lower rate. Try lightening your project and its quality as long as you are working on its fundamental features, because you can add details later. Try reducing the size of your history and undo list to a lower capacity and number. (Meaning that you wouldn't be able to do a lot of undos).

Also You might want to make sure that this is the appropriate edition of Adobe Flash Pro CS for your system. (Like it might be better if you tried the X64 edition).